# Authenticate user updates using JWT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to let the user update their information by logging in and then update it through the JWT header, but I can't. It keeps returning failed confirmation.

I want when the user logs in successfully, the information will be updated

my code

UserValidate

```
export default async function UserValidate(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // access authorize header to validate request
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

    // retrive the user details fo the logged in user
    const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.user = decodedToken;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Authentication Failed!" });
  }
}
```

update user

```
export async function updateUser(req, res) {
  try {
    const { ID } = req.params;

    if (ID) {
      const {
        USERNAME,
        EMAIL,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        DATE_OF_BIRTH,
        MOBILE,
        ADDRESS,
        AVATAR,
      } = req.body;

      const query = `
        UPDATE users 
        SET 
          USERNAME = ?, 
          EMAIL = ?, 
          FIRST_NAME = ?, 
          LAST_NAME = ?, 
          DATE_OF_BIRTH = ?, 
          MOBILE = ?, 
          ADDRESS = ?, 
          AVATAR = ? 
        WHERE ID = ?`;

      const values = [
        USERNAME,
        EMAIL,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        DATE_OF_BIRTH,
        MOBILE,
        ADDRESS,
        AVATAR,
        ID,
      ];

      await connection.query(query, values, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error updating user:", err);
          return res.status(500).send({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
        }

        return res.status(201).send({ msg: "Record Updated...!" });
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: "User Not Found...!" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user:", error);
    return res.status(500).send({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```

route update

```
router.route("/auth/update-user").put(userValidation, updateUser);
```

postman test

[image]

postman login

[image]

I tried putting Bearer in the Header section

[image]

Comment: see how you have `catch (error)` in `UserValidate` but you ignore the value of `error`? It may contain some useful information you are ignoring - and it's NOT coming back with `failed confirmation` - the error YOU output is `Authentication Failed`

Comment: You don't seem to be sending an `authorization` header, yet your `UserValidate` function expects it

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are trying to read the Bearer token from the "authorization" header value. And from the postman configuration there's no "authorization" header containing the bearer token as a value.
It should be:

authorization: "Bearer {token}"

I hope this helps.